# Build Arduino library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, arduino

I've tried to build a library (file.cpp + file.h) to Arduino but I got this error:

> In file included from EXAMPLE_MPL3115A2.ino:2:
>   /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/MPL3115A2/MPL3115A2.h:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'getPressure' with no type
>   EXAMPLE_MPL3115A2.ino: In function 'void loop()':
>   EXAMPLE_MPL3115A2:18: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Can you explain me where is the error?? (I don't know very well C++)

Here are my **MPL3115A2.h**

```
#ifndef MPL3115A2_h
#define MPL3115A2_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class MPL3115A2{
public:
  getPressure();
private:
  int m_i2c_address;
  byte _p_msb, _p_csb, _plsb;
  byte _tempp, _tempa, _tempt, _decimalPress, _decimalAlt, _decimalTemp;
  unsigned long _ptot;
};

#endif
```

my **MPL3115A2.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "MPL3115A2.h"
#include "I2C.h"



MPL3115A2::MPL3115A2()
{
        m_i2c_address = 0x60;
        p_msb = _p_msb;
    p_csb = _p_csb;
    p_lsb = _p_lsb;
        tempp = _tempp;
    tempa = _tempa;
    tempt = _tempt;
    decimalPress = _decimalPress;
    decimalAlt = _decimalAlt;
    decimalTemp = _decimalTemp;
        ptot = _ptot;
}

float MPL3115A2::getPressure()
{
  I2c.write(m_i2c_address,0x26,0x00);
  I2c.write(m_i2c_address,0x26,0x01); 
  delay(100);
  I2c.read(m_i2c_address,0x1,3);
  I2c.end();
  while(I2c.available()){
  p_msb=I2c.receive(); 
  p_csb=I2c.receive(); 
  p_lsb=I2c.receive();}
    ptot=p_msb;
  ptot=(ptot<<8)+p_csb;
  ptot=(ptot<<2)+(p_lsb>>6);
  tempp=(p_lsb<<2);
  if(tempp==192){
    decimalPress=75;
  }else if(tempp==128){
    decimalPress=25;
  }else if(tempp==64){
    decimalPress=5;
  }else{tempp=0;}
  Serial.print(ptot);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(decimalPress);
}

#endif
```

and my **example.pde**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MPL3115A2.h>
#include <I2C.h>

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  I2c.begin();
}
//LOOP
void loop(){
  Serial.print("Pressure is: ");
  MPL3115A2.getPressure(); //Expressed in Pa
  Serial.print("Altimetry is: ");
  //MPL3115A2.getAltimetry(); //Expressed in m
  Serial.print("Temperature is: ");
 // MPL3115A2.getTemperature();  //Expressed in C
  delay(2000);
}
```

Sorry for the long post!
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: down vote cowards need to post their reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPressure()` has no return type!  According to the cpp you posted, your header file should **declare** the method as `float getPressure();` so change your header file to:

```
#ifndef MPL3115A2_h
#define MPL3115A2_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class MPL3115A2{
public:
  float getPressure(); // <- only change here
private:
  int m_i2c_address;
  byte _p_msb, _p_csb, _plsb;
  byte _tempp, _tempa, _tempt, _decimalPress, _decimalAlt, _decimalTemp;
  unsigned long _ptot;
};

#endif
```

to correspond with the **definition** which is

```
float MPL3115A2::getPressure()
{
  // your processing code...
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you should review your `constructor` as it is not **declared** in your header. Also, doing something like

```
p_msb = _p_msb;
p_csb = _p_csb;
p_lsb = _p_lsb;
tempp = _tempp;
tempa = _tempa;
tempt = _tempt;
decimalPress = _decimalPress;
decimalAlt = _decimalAlt;
decimalTemp = _decimalTemp;
ptot = _ptot;
```

is really weird. What are the variables on the left?  You are initializing them with your uninitialized members (those on the right, starting with `_`). You should consider giving an initial value to these members (like `0`?)

Changing your constructor to something like:

```
MPL3115A2::MPL3115A2()
{
    _p_msb = 0;
    _p_csb = 0;
    _p_lsb = 0;
    _tempp = 0;
    _tempa = 0;
    _tempt = 0;
    _decimalPress = 0;
    _decimalAlt = 0;
    _decimalTemp = 0;
    _ptot = 0;
}
```

To make sure your member variables are initialized with a "known" value.

Also, most of these values seem temporary (you might not need them outside of a call to `getPressure()`. In this case, consider moving all these bytes to the scope of the function instead of inside the sensor class to avoid using unnecessary memory - there is not that much available on Arduinos.

You will also need to add `MPL3115A2();` in the `public` part of your `MPL3115A2` class, this is because you are defining a body for this constructor in the CPP file, therefore you need to declare it so that it's part of the object.

Comment: Or actually `float MPL3115A2::getPressure()` as can be seen in `MPL3115A2.cpp`above :-)

Comment: @emartel you were right of course - I deleted the answer - was distracted

Comment: @8bit_Biker for example, your constructor assings `ptot` with `_ptot`. In the code you provided, `ptot` doesn't exist and `_ptot` wasn't given an initial value yet!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your advice. These are "temp" vars corresponding to the pressure/altitude/etc sensor's register (pressure most significant byte... and so on), so I thought to consider them as temporary variable. But you must consider I'm far for being a programmer!So, I really appreciate if you could show me how it is the most correct way to use it

Comment: Moreover.. Thank you all very very much for your help! really appreciated!!

Comment: @8bit_Biker edited the answer with more info, let me know if you need more infos

Comment: @emartel: I've just done the fix...but it continue to give me one more errors! (I know that starting to study hard C++ is the better way to understand all this problems!!!)
I'm able to communicate with this sensor using the Arduino IDE, but I would like to implement the library to have a better and well organized code. 
The new error is: 
"
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/MPL3115A2/MPL3115A2.cpp:7: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'MPL3115A2::MPL3115A2()'"
Can you help me to understand it??
Thank you very much.

Comment: @8bit_Biker you probably just need to add `MPL3115A2();` right before your `float getPressure();` in your header file to declare that you will be providing a constructor :)

Comment: @emartel: this last one seems to fix it up! No errors appear after the  verification. Can you explain me what I've done using your advice??

Comment: @emartel: Hi! The library doesn't cause errors anymore, but while I'm expecting to have some sensor value printed in the Arduino's serial monitor, I can't get anything. It prints every time (0.0, 0.0, etc...). If I wrote the function in the Arduino's sketch directly, instead of using the library, the sensor answers right to me (As I expect), giving to me something like this "98341, 98343"(values are expressed in Pascal). Can you help me also in this case??

Comment: @8bit_Biker I am surprised `MPL3115A2.getPressure(); //Expressed in Pa` even works. Create a `MPL3115A2` object like `MPL3115A2 mySensor;` then call `getPressure` on it (`mySensor.getPressure();`) or change getPressure and all the variables to be `static` and call it using `MPL3115A2::getPressure();`

Comment: It still doesn't work. No matter... I continue to use the functions inside the arduino's sketch, instead of create library. It is very strange!I was thinking making the library was definitely more easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that the `getPressure()` method should be declared with the return type `float` as you implement it in `MPL3115A2.cpp`, so the `'h` file should have:

```
...
class MPL3115A2 {
    public:
        float getPressure();
        // (and remember the constructor)
    private:    
        ...
}
```

Also, are you aware that the method doesn't actually `return` anything? If that is the idea, you could make it a `void getPressure()` and change the class definition accordingly.

**Added**: For future readers, the answer is available in the error message, albeit well hidden in cryptic stuff: "*...ISO C++ forbids **declaration** of 'getPressure' with **no type**...*"

Hope that helps.